# Find test-classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, testing

I want to learn programming with eclipse. Therefore I started to get to know this tool. I have a project with some classes and test-classes ( which all had a "test" in there names). Now I am looking for a shortcut or something like a search field to type in the the word "test" to find all the test-classes.

Would be nice if i could get some help

Answer (score 2):

You can search for classes by their name in Eclipse using the **Open Type** dialog.

To open it, you can use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.

[image: Open Type]

Answer (score 1):

You can search with field @Test to get all test class 
 ctrl + shift + R.(@Test)

Comment: no this is not working.. I dont get any result by typing @ or @test

Comment: ctrl + shift + R searches for resource files by name. This does not work.